# Button elements are supposed to be input elements, but the .click() method fails on many button elements that should be clickable

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I am trying to use dotnetbrowser to log into facebook currently, but I have run into this issue with other button elements on a few different sites.

facebook login page has elements with ID attributes: "name", "pass" and "login" for username, password, and submit login button respectively.  Getting these name and pass elements and setting their values to the appropriate text works just fine.  However, login.click() does not respond.  I have tried setting its focus first as well, and tried casting as an inputElement.  .click works elsewhere, like dropdown lists etc.  There is no field format issues, as sending the enter key with password field focused does indeed successfully log in.  Please don't ask why I don't just do that then, because I find this .click() method unresponsive in many places where simply using chromedriver on the same element would have no problem.  It makes working with automation much harder with dotnetbrowser, having to try and tab and use return all the time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in this case, while "user" and "pass" input elements have id attributes, the "login" button element has name attribute, and no id attribute.  Silly oversite.